# Qt adjust value relatively using regular expression

Tags: c++, qt

I have some HTML (excerpt)

```html
<span style="font-size:30pt;">HELLO</span>
```

I have this html stored in a QString.

I wish to reduce the font size by a factor. For simplicity sake let's halve it, so I need it changed to

```html
<span style="font-size:15pt;">HELLO</span>
```

Can I apply [QString::replace()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-12) here somehow?
The only examples I have seen replace absolute, but mine needs to read the current value and apply simple math on it, then write it back.

FWIW, I have this expression worked out:

```
<span.+font-size:(\d+)pt;.*?>
```

I don't think it really matters that this question places it in context of HTML.
I suppose it could apply to any string.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`QRegularExpression`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html).

Calling `QRegularExpression::match()`, it will return a [`QRegularExpressionMatch`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatch.html) that will give you access to captured strings.

Then you will have to parse the string to a number, do the maths and rebuild the final string.

Note that Qt provides a useful example program for QRegularExpression: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-regularexpression-example.html
If you are using Qt Creator you can open it from the Welcome page.

Also note that using regular expression to parse HTML does not work well.
If you are sure that you will get a simple HTML it can work, but if the HTML is coming from untrusted sources, you could end up with a mix of HTML, CSS and JavaScript that won't match your regular expression.